Is the extension of saturated ideals still saturated?
Let $K$ be a field, $S:=K[x_0,...,x_n]$. For any homogeneous ideal $I$ of $S$, we say $I$ is saturated if $I=\lbrace s\in S\mid \text{for each }i=0,...,n, \text{there is a }m, x_i^ms\in I\rbrace$.
Now, let $L/K$ be any field extension, and we have $I^e$ defined in $L[x_0,...,x_n]$ by the canonical inlcusion $K[x_0,...,x_n]\hookrightarrow L[x_0,...,x_n]$. My question is, is that true $I^e$ is also a saturated ideal?
